# How to explicitly release GDI handles allocated by TForm derived class owned by the Application?

Tags: delphi, resources, c++builder, gdi

A single class derived from TForm appears to hold onto GDI handles until the application is closed.

```
class TTestForm : public TForm {
  public:
    TTestForm(TComponent*);
};

std::auto_ptr<TTestForm> test(new TTestForm(NULL));
test->ShowModal();
```

I'm quite new to VCL, so please bear with me. This test was done with a form that contains no controls. As far as I udnerstand, all objects are owned by the Application if no owner is specified.

My application creates (and destroys) a lot of forms dynamically. 3-4 new GDI handles are allocated each time a form is displayed. Is there a way to explicitly release those GDI handles during application lifetime?

Comment: Where are you declaring the auto_ptr? If it is in global scope, as it appears above, it won't go out of scope, and thus won't call the destructor for the object. (When you use NULL as the Owner, it means that you will manage the destruction and it won't be done automatically by the VCL)

Comment: @David: No. This is just a simplified example. The auto_ptr is usually created inside another forms' member function. I do indeed want to manage the destruction. However, when auto_ptr goes out of scope, 3-4 GDI handles appear to be leaked each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the leak was caused by an incorrectly set TImageList.ShareImages property.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I'm a Delphi programmer, not C++, but the VCL is basically the VCL.  You can try the form's Release() method instead of free().  Or alternatively, in the OnClose event set the Action parameter passed to *caFree* - thats supposed to tell the VCL to free the window's resources when the form closes, rather than hiding it.

I guess another question is - do you need to keep creating/destroying the forms?  Can you create them once and then reuse them?

Comment: I believe I've tried both options and they made no difference. I will double check again.  
Keeping the forms alive is simply not an option.

Comment: You might check Emb's site to see if this is a know problem.  Its possible there's a leak in 2007 that just cant be gotten around using vcl methods.

Also, is it possible that there's something on the forms that are leaking?  ie, its not the form itself, but one of the controls?  Does the same problem occur if you specify an owner?